# How to acces the confusion matrix or get more metrics from LAzyPredic Classifier?

Tags: confusion-matrix, automl, lazypredict

I'm running a LazyClassiffier and I need to calculate some metrics that don't come as defaul in the output, the default only prints Accuracy, Balnced Accuracy, ROC AUC, adn F1 Score.
I need to estimate the Sensitivity (Recall), Precision, Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC), all of which can be calculated from the confusion matrix (FP, TP, FN, TN), but I can't find a way to do it, and is not in the LazyPredict documentation either.

the basic code is:

```
clf = LazyClassifier()
models, preictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

and the print looks like:

```
                         Accuracy  Balanced Accuracy  ROC AUC  F1 Score  \
```

Model
ExtraTreesClassifier               0.93               0.90     0.90      0.93
LGBMClassifier                     0.89               0.84     0.84      0.89
XGBClassifier                      0.89               0.84     0.84      0.89
RandomForestClassifier             0.89               0.84     0.84      0.89

I have a few methos and even asking GPT, but no results